# How does V8 implement primitive-valued keys for `Map`s?

Tags: javascript, v8

I assume V8 uses hashing in order to use objects as keys in `Map`s.

```js
const a = {};
new Map([[a, "a"]]);
```

**Question Part 1**: How does V8 implement maps with primitive-valued keys, such as the following?

```
const a = {};
new Map([[a, "a"], [1, 100], [2, 200])
```

**Question Part 2**:

How about a map like this, which contains *only* primitive-valued keys, where those keys are all of the same type?

`new Map([[0, 0], [1, 100], [2, 200])`

The most efficient way of mapping numbers to numbers that I know of is to use a vector, such that the map above could be implemented like this:

`[0, 100, 200]`

Does V8 do any sort of specialization 
along these lines?

I benchmarked to compare Map to an array of numbers and found number[] to be 37% faster (roughly as expected), but am not sure exactly what is going on: https://jsperf.com/map-number-number-vs-array.

*Note that in the benchmark the array and map are built up dynamically rather than all-in-one-shot like in the examples above*.

Comment: "*I assume V8 uses hashing in order to use objects as keys*" - why do you assume that, and does this matter to the rest of the question? It sounds a bit like you want to imply that primitive values couldn't be hashed.

Comment: I'm pretty certain that V8 doesn't use a vector to implement integer-keyed `Map`s. For one, maps can be very sparse and should still be efficient, unlike a vector. And second, maps do need to keep creation order of keys, which a vector doesn't.

Comment: You can try to search inside V8 source code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

V8 developer here. V8 implements all `Map`s the same way: they're hash maps, and they compute the hash of the key. Computing a hash for numbers like `0`, `1`, etc is really simple, so there is no particular challenge around that.

V8 does not do any special-casing based on seeing only keys of a particular type. The idea is: if you use a `Map`, you're signalling to the engine that you want a hash map implementation because you'll have arbitrary keys and want them all handled equally well. If, on the other hand, you know that your keys will always be a dense set of small numbers, you can use an `Array` instead of a `Map`, which will indeed be more efficient (in terms of both memory and performance) for that particular case. More power to you!

Comment: Thanks! How do you hash 0?

Comment: Just like any other integer; in V8's case like this: https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/v8/src/utils/utils.h?q=ComputeUnseededHash&sq=package:chromium&g=0&l=480

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that V8 does not specialize Maps (or Sets) for primitive values. Now let's dive a bit deeper.

First of all, we need to understand what kind of algorithm is used for Maps. "Classical" hash tables won't do as they do not provide any iteration order guarantees, while ES6 spec requires insertion to be in the iteration order. So, Maps in V8 are built on top of so-called [deterministic hash tables](https://wiki.mozilla.org/User:Jorend/Deterministic_hash_tables). The idea is similar to the classical algorithm, but there is another layer of indirection for buckets and all entries are inserted and stored in a contiguous array of a fixed size.

Considering this, for [Smis](https://medium.com/fhinkel/v8-internals-how-small-is-a-small-integer-e0badc18b6da) V8 may store key/value in-place, but for larger numbers, strings, objects, and other stuff hash table entry will store pointers.

As for the benchmarks, it's a controversial topic, but I'd expect a plain fixed-size array to be more efficient in terms of reads when compared with a Map. That's because it does not involve the overhead of a hash table, like hash code calculation and moves over bucket chains.

Finally, if you're still curious how V8 Maps work under the hood, you may find more details [here](https://itnext.io/v8-deep-dives-understanding-map-internals-45eb94a183df). I was interested in the topic some time ago and tried to share my findings in a readable manner.